# Data Validation Implementation

Tags: validation, e-commerce, client-side, server-side

When doing data validation such as email or any user registration, what is the choice in implementation? Client-side, server-side or any other choice?

Answer (score 0):

It's a convenience for your users to do some client side validation, but you *have* to do server side validation because client side validation can be turned off or dodged.